# checkout to remote branch which is fetched locally

Tags: git

I have a remote branch:

```
git branch -a
*master
 remotes/origin/develop
```

Can I checkout to `remotes/origin/develop` ? Or should I always create clone of remote branches locally?

Comment: `git pull origin develop` will create a local branch `develop` which tracks the remote one.

Comment: In reasonably current versions of git (>= 1.7.something I think), you can just `git checkout develop` to create a local tracking branch.  If this doesn't work, `git checkout -b develop --track origin/develop` should at least work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to clone your remote branches locally if you want to make changes in the remote. When you checkout a remote branch by issuing `git checkout remotes/origin/develop`, you will go into a `detached HEAD` state, which essentially means you are not on any branch right then.

Comment: Right, `detached HEAD` is exactly where I got when I tried. Can you please elaborate on why this happens?

Comment: It basically means you are not bound to a branch. You are just referring to one particular commit. Check the Detached Head section in this link: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout